# firebase get list of child node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have the following structure on my firebase

```
"users" : {
"06f0536d-2326-43a0-81db-9e94acc77b4e" : {
  "address" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "displayName" : "xxxxxxx",
  "email" : "xxx@xxx.com",
  "fleet" : {
    "-K6iGFIu5Jwu_AmWWDTL" : {
      "avafrom" : 1451343600000,
      "avauntil" : 1454540400000,
      "brands" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "desc" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "dmile" : 5,
      "drate" : 22,
    },
    "-K6iGUY6Y19PExwBklal" : {
      "avafrom" : 1451516400000,
      "avauntil" : 1454540400000,
      "brands" : "xxxxx",
      "desc" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "dmile" : 5,
      "drate" : 12,
     }
  },
  "phone" : "+49xxxxxxx",
  "role" : "xxxxxxxxxxx"
},
"22dbc365-3201-4bc0-9f19-2a8a64bea235" : {
  "address" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "displayName" : "xxxx",
  "email" : "xxxx@xxxx.com",
  "fleet" : {
    "-K6ge_Y4enb_a13O1eCu" : {
      "avafrom" : 1451343600000,
      "avauntil" : 1451516400000,
      "brands" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "desc" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "dmile" : 1,
      "drate" : 22,
    },
    "-K6gexE9KXd3WGBnjIY8" : {
      "avafrom" : 1451343600000,
      "avauntil" : 1451516400000,
      "brands" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "desc" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "dmile" : 1,
      "drate" : 22,
    }
  },
  "phone" : "+49xxxxxx",
  "role" : "xxxxxxx"
},
```

and **How to get the list of fleet of all users with this?** i have tried the following:

```
var ref = new Firebase(fb+'users');
        return {
            fleet: function(){
                ref.orderByChild("fleet").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                    console.log("data trucks", snapshot.val());
                    return snapshot.val();
                })
            }
        }
```

but i ended up of getting all users data, not only their fleet. I'm not even sure if I'm doing it right, I'm trying to make 1 to many relationship here, every users can have a fleet which consist of a list of car. I'm new into Firebase, and English isn't my native language, so i don't really understand their doc, i think if someone can give me an example to do this, it will be a great help

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the `fleet` nodes, you'll need to restructure your data. When you read data from a parent node, you'll get all of the children nodes as well.

You can key off of the `uid` for `fleet`, here's an example:

```
{
   "users": {
      "06f0536d-2326-43a0-81db-9e94acc77b4e" : {
         "address" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "displayName" : "xxxxxxx",
         "email" : "xxx@xxx.com"
      }
   },
   "fleet": {
      "06f0536d-2326-43a0-81db-9e94acc77b4e" : {
         "-K6ge_Y4enb_a13O1eCu" : {
            "avafrom" : 1451343600000,
            "avauntil" : 1451516400000,
            "brands" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "desc" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "dmile" : 1,
            "drate" : 22
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You also can't return from an async function.

```
ref.orderByChild("fleet").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  return snapshot.val(); // won't work
})
```

The data has to download over the network, so it won't happen synchronously.

You could pass in a callback:

```
function FleetFactory() {
  var ref = new Firebase(fb+'users');
  return {
    fleet: function(callback){
      ref.orderByChild("fleet").on("child_added", callback);
    }
  }
}

function MyController(FleetFactory) {
   FleetFactory.fleet(function(snap) {
      console.log(snap.val());
   });
}
```

But, it's still not your ideal situation.

**[Use AngularFire, which wraps each Firebase event to a synchronized array.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)**

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function MyController($scope, rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.fleet = $firebaseArray(rootRef.child('fleet'));
}
```

Don't try to `console.log($scope.fleet)`, because it will initially show up empty, because the data is still downloading. However, once the data has downloaded it will trigger the `$digest` loop and the data will appear on the page.

Try doing `json` filter in your template to test:

```
<pre>{{ fleet | json ||</pre>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have tried callbacks methods, but it still give me all object of users tree, i only need to get a list of fleet from all users, not the all data from users. and for 2nd method using an array from my controller, it returns an empty array, maybe because of unique id from each fleet item? it seems it can't find a child node from fleet

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to get the list of all users fleet, but how can i show e.g this fleet owned by "displayName", currently im using ng-repeat="item in fleet" to iterate fleet array, but I'm confused about how to get the fleet ownership data from the other nodes.